# failure multiple projects doing xcopy to same folder in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cmd, dos

We have several projects that have a "templates" folder that all get copied to the same "templates" folder in our shared bin directory.  Intermittently we get xcopy failures.

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4429,5): error MSB3073: The command "xcopy /s /y /r "E:\Source\DotNet\Service Providers\ActionScheduler\Templates" "E:\Source\DotNet\bin\x64\Release\Service Providers..\Templates\"" exited with code 4

These are post build steps that are being run in devenv.

I'm wondering if anyone has a suggestion to reduce or remove these errors.

Perhaps there is an alternative to xcopy which is more robust?

All of the templates folders that get copied have a subfolder "EN" and some files under that directory.

Additional information:

```
  <message>98>  Sharing violation</message>
  <message>98>  0 File(s) copied</message>
  <message>98>  Unable to create directory - E:\Source\DotNet\bin\x64\Release\Templates</message>
  <message>98>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4429,5): error MSB3073: The command "xcopy /s /y /r "E:\Source\DotNet\Service Providers\ActionScheduler\Templates" "E:\Source\DotNet\bin\x64\Release\Service Providers\..\Templates\"" exited with code 4.</message>
```

The error still occurred after adding /d.  I also tried pre-creating the folder in a prebuild step of a project that would get build earlier.  But I still got the following error:

```
98>  Sharing violation
98>  Unable to create directory - E:\Source\DotNet\bin\x64\Release\Templates
98>  0 File(s) copied
98>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4429,5): error MSB3073: The command "xcopy /s /y /r /d "E:\Source\DotNet\Service Providers\ActionScheduler\Templates" "E:\Source\DotNet\bin\x64\Release\Service Providers\..\Templates\"" exited with code 4.
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to look in the Output window for a diagnostic message from XCopy when this error occurs.  "Intermittent" is pretty hard to explain without that diagnostic.

There is certainly a good way to greatly reduce the chances for this going wrong.  You are copying these files over and over again for no good reason.  Add the `/D` option, that only copies when a file does not yet exist or has changed.  So you basically only copy these files once and about never again, can't fail that way :)

---

After edit: yeah, that sure looks like two post-builds trying to copy the same file at the same time.  Unlucky timing, anti-malware has a knack for extending it too long while it scans the file.  You need to fix that, one is enough.  With *very* high odds that /D already fixes it.

Comment: Drats!  Still got the error after adding the /d.  Also checked, there is no anti-virus running on the build server.

Comment: Well, do you have more than one post-build event copying the same files?   Don't.

Answer (score 0):

Code 4 means:
*"Initialization error occurred. There is not enough memory or disk space, or you entered an **invalid drive name or invalid syntax** on the command line."*

Is E:\Source\DotNet\bin\x64\Release\Service Providers..\Templates\

OK? dotdot???

Comment: My apologies.  I somehow must have deleted a slash, I have edited the question.  The project builds fine on it's own, it seems to be a conflict with multiple projects doing xcopy to the same folder in parallel ( compiler builds projects in parallel ).

Answer (score 0):

If you have several projects building the same output named support files you could try to turn off parallel builds.  [MSDN link for setting this option](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0xettzf(v=vs.90).aspx)
However this looks like a system wide setting an not just for that project.  As a last resort you could attempt to stop the copying of the files for all but one project by setting the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Do not copy".

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, from the MSDN documentation here we added the following switches. Im my case the I switch seemed to do the trick.

> Xcopy /Y /I  /S

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771254.aspx